# detect not closed html tags in a text, and fix it

Tags: javascript, php

I have an html text called **news** which is generated by ckeditor, so it may contain html tags like bold, italic, paragraph and.... 
I want to choose the first 100 characters of it and show them to the users of my app. but choosing the first 100 characters of **news** may cause to choose an html text which has unclosed tags(the closing tags of my html text may be after the character number 100).
is there any PHP or js function to parse a text and fix the unclosed html tags or at least remove unclosed html tags?

Comment: instead of characters why not a X amount of words

Comment: `tidy` php extension

Comment: X amount of word does not fit to the provided area for my news, I need exactly 100 characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as removing tags altogether, the `strip_tags` function in PHP should do the trick.

```
strip_tags($input, '<br><br/>');
```

The second argument is the allowed tags (the ones that don't get stripped).

Comment: there is no way to close, unclosed tags? should I remove them all?

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the HTML Tags by using the PHP function strip_tags().

```
<?php
$text = '<h1>Test Header. <b>On Example</b>';
echo strip_tags($text);

// Output: Test Header. On Example

?>
```

Please check the reference on the function at https://secure.php.net/strip_tags

Side Note:

I have a function to chopContent that you could use, to get the first 100 characters:

```
public function chopContent($content, $content_length = 100)

{

    if (strlen($content) > $content_length) {
        $offset = ($content_length - 13) - strlen($content);
        $content = mb_substr($content, 0, strrpos($content, ' ', $offset)) . '...';
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Tidy is a binding for the Tidy HTML clean and repair utility which allows you to not only clean and otherwise manipulate HTML documents, but also traverse the document tree.

[Try this](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/)